# How to fill the area near the y axis in a plot?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, fill

I need to plot two features of a dataframe where df['DEPTH'] should be inverted and at y-axis and df['SPECIES'] should be at x-axis. Imagining that the plot would be a variant line, I would like to fill with color the area near the y-axis (left side of the line). So I wrote some code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550],
               'SPECIES':[12, 8, 9, 6, 10, 7, 4, 3, 1, 2]})

plt.plot(df['SPECIES'], df['DEPTH'])
plt.fill_between(df['SPECIES'], df['DEPTH'])

plt.ylabel('DEPTH')
plt.xlabel('SPECIES')

plt.ylim(np.max(df['DEPTH']), np.min(df['DEPTH']))
```

I tried 'plt.fill_between', but then the left part of the plot doesn't get all filled.

[image]
[image]

Anyone knows how can the filled part (blue color) reach the y-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `fill_between`, you can use [`fill_betweenx`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_betweenx.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_betweenx). It will start filling from 0 by default, thus you need to set your x limit to be 0 too.

```
plt.plot(df['SPECIES'], df['DEPTH'])
# changing fill_between to fill_betweenx -- the order also changes
plt.fill_betweenx(df['DEPTH'], df['SPECIES'])

plt.ylabel('DEPTH')
plt.xlabel('SPECIES')

plt.ylim(np.max(df['DEPTH']), np.min(df['DEPTH']))
# setting the lower limit to 0 for the filled area to reach y axis.
plt.xlim(0,np.max(df['SPECIES']))

plt.show()
```

The result is below.

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot @ilke444!